# How do I use JavaScript frameworks with Opa

Tags: javascript, opa

Is it possible to use existing frontend frameworks like Sproutcore and ExtJS with Opa?

If so, where can I find documentation about it?

Answer (score 3):

Good timing -- I just wrote a [blog post](http://blog.opalang.org/2012/01/reusing-javascript-libraries-jquery-ui.html) about using external JS libraries (plugins) with Opa. Hope you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Opa can interact with js external libraries with Opa plugins, it may be used to get contents generated by those frameworks. Or iframe... What would want to do exactly, in the framework side and on the Opa side?

About Opa plugins: http://blog.erlware.org/2011/11/23/opa-plugin-development-with-a-pubnub-example/